# Yii2: Not Found (#404): Unable to find debug data tagged with '5578effb0790c4.13707485'

Tags: php, yii2

I'm getting this at the bottom of my page, where the debug bar should be. What is the problem?

This request: `http://localhost:81/xxx/web/debug/default/toolbar?tag=5578f180963e82.28312577` is returning 404.

I need to see the error message & stack trace generated when I log to `Yii::error()`. It's not showing in `runtime/log/app.log`, so I need the debug bar.

Comment: I restarted my Apache and it worked again, but not before I had trouble with Apache and had to delete semaphores with `ipcs` and `ipcrm`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I removed files from `frontend/runtime/debug` and `frontend/runtime/cache` and nothing was changed.

But when I removed all folders from `frontend/runtime` then it started to work.

Comment: worked for me too. ran into this issue after updating Yii to the latest version 2.0.14 to 2.0.15.1.

Comment: After removing everything from  ` frontend/runtime`  I got a much bigger error now; `Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException`
`Session save path is not a valid directory:` `/var/www/myproj/frontend/config/../runtime/sessions`
What can I do?

Comment: Looks like you store session under runtime/sessions folder. This is not default configuration, so you can try to create this folder manually.
Check your settings Example: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/767/yii2-configuring-different-sessions-for-backend-and-frontend-in-yii-advanced-application-template

Answer (score 10):

One reason could be missing write permissions for the `runtime` folder. The Debug Tool Bar creates there another directory `debug` which is used for *.data files.

This happens easily if the web server has its own user which differs to the user that has created the runtime folder.

Comment: I had changed the permissions to the runtime folder,and I restared Apache sever,but I found the permissions of this folder turn back only read

Comment: Are you sure? This sounds strange. Do you have any special configurations?

Comment: I had known the reason why I got this 404 error.Cause I added a captcha input in my form,and it will send a request like `url\captcha?tag=5578f180963e82.28312577`.My site works  again when I comment that captcha.I try add captcha again,it still work well,then I don't know why yet.About the permissions,My folders can be written to a file,just show read-only. In the end,sorry for my english  -_-b

Answer (score 5):

I tried the info above without luck (and I suggest people here do the same, as in most circumstances it will solve your problem). But what worked for me was running.
`tail -f frontend/runtime/logs/app.log` and it told me that there was an error with a table that it expected to exist but did not. Once I fixed that underlying issue my problem went away.
In my specific case, I had the following enabled but no corresponding table/s.

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
],
```

Once I commented/removed it from my config, everything started working.

Comment: Glad to have played a part in helping you :)

Answer (score 0):

i tried the removal of runtime folders but it didn't change a thing
but a composer update fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for it not working is attaching [HttpBearerAuth](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-httpbearerauth) filter to the main application (not a specific controller).
After removing the global filter, it suddenly works again. Not sure how to make it work *with* the filter. I will update this answer if I ever find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Give **read/write/execute(777)** permission to your project folder. This will work for you. It works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade of `yiisoft/yii2-debug` library to latest(2.1.22) version resolved issue in my case.

Comment: Hi. `latest` is may not the best when the answer is read in a few years. May you can share the exact version number.