# Yii2 debug bar not showing on staging server even with allowedIP's entry

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to get the debug bar in `Yii2` to show on my staging server but for some reason it isn't showing.

Here is code from my `web.php` config file:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
                                   'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
                                   'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1','::1','123.45.67.89']
                                   ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}
```

`123.45.67.89` obviously is just an example for the server's real IP.

I get the servers IP by doing:

```
$host = gethostname();
$server_ip = gethostbyname($host);
```

If I try and access the debug page by going to:

http://www.example.com/debug/default/index

I get the message: *You are not allowed to access this page.*

I am sure I had this working before but now it's not working for some reason and I can't figure out why!?

I'm aware there are debug data files (not sure if they will contain any info on why I can't see it) but I am not sure how I can view the data properly?

Comment: Can you access gii? If not, your environment is probably set to PRODUCTION.

Comment: @topher No I cannot access Gii either. But I ran an echo inside `if (YII_ENV_DEV) {` in the `web.php` config file and it outputs, so not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Might be something to do with the runtime logs: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770524/yii2-not-found-404-unable-to-find-debug-data-tagged-with-5578effb0790c4-13

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AllowedIPs` parameter should contain your ip, check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for it and set it into `AllowedIPs`. See how gii [check access](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/Module.php#L137)

Answer (score 10):

i know this is old but it may help someone now since this isn't very clear anywhere on the web.

We used to have this problem a lot when deploying to test and dev servers. Add this to your main-local.php

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['*']
    ];
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}
```

DO NOT DO THIS ON A PRODUCTION SERVER!!!!

Comment: didn't believe that the `'allowedIPs' => ['*']` would do the trick, but you sir, are a life savier

Answer (score 3):

Check what you have in your `frontend/web/index.php` or `app/web/index.php`

you need

```
<?php
  defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
  defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Comment: Yes, I have those, not commented out.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a custom layout, make sure you are calling `<?php $this->endBody() ?>` before your `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `[yii-app-folder]/runtime/debug` folder is writeable by the http server (Apache, nginx, etc).

Example:

```
sudo chown www-data: ./runtime/debug/ -R
```

Answer (score 0):

If you running nginx & php-fpm, I had to restart the service.

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check your `/backend/runtime/` directory and make sure its writeable